# Generalised Cauchy Integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

Is the step I have highlighted in the proof incorrect? We only know $f$ is holomorphic for $|z|<1$, so why are we able to use the generalised Cauchy's formula on the curve |$z|=1$?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistake that can be corrected by letting $0 < \rho < 1$ and choosing the contour of integration to be $|z| = \rho$, instead of $|z| = 1$. Then the ML inequality gives $|a_k| \le \rho^{-k}$. Letting $\rho \to 1^{-}$, deduce $|a_k| \le 1$.